# How to enter input during rspec testing?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

So I need to create an object and it requires me to enter some input during the initialization of the object. But rspec won't allow me to do this, it doesn't pause the testing for me to enter the input instead it just keeps executing resulting in the test failing since its a nil object.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your application code and your test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rspec does not stop to allow you to enter input - that's not what it is for. rspec is to test what would happen if you *had* entered various inputs.

The way to do this is to set up code that passes in various kinds of information, and checks that your object does what it should once you've entered it.

We can't help you any more than this (or help you to set up an example) until you show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of googling I found a work around. 
Using mocks i.e.

`@player = instance_double('Player', :name => 'John')`

Then you can use the following call

`@player.name`

I apologise for the formatting this is my first time using stackoverflow.